# Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've set up a MongoDB cluster on Atlas and have been able to connect to it from Compass and a NodeJs app I'm building for about a week.  today I started getting consistently the "transient" error below from the NodeJs app:

> { MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to
>   cluster0-shard-00-01-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net:27017 closed
>       at TLSSocket. (/Users/ekkis/dev/tst/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:276:9)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:15)
>       at _handle.close (net.js:610:12)
>       at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:386:7)   name: 'MongoNetworkError',   errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

even though Compass seems to work fine.  it's very slow sometimes but it works.  so I tried installing the shell (v4.0.0 on OSX) and got this:

```
$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net/test" --username tst
```

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.0 Enter password:  connecting to:
>   mongodb+srv://cluster0-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net/test
>   2019-02-24T16:48:07.460-0800 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set
>   monitor for
>   Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net.:27017
>   2019-02-24T16:48:09.971-0800 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary
>   for set Cluster0-shard-0 2019-02-24T16:48:09.971-0800 I NETWORK  [js]
>   Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network
>   connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks
>   in a row. 2019-02-24T16:48:13.260-0800 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach
>   primary for set Cluster0-shard-0 2019-02-24T16:48:13.260-0800 I
>   NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please
>   check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has
>   happened for 2 checks in a row. 2019-02-24T16:48:16.880-0800 W NETWORK
>   [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
>   2019-02-24T16:48:16.880-0800 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes
>   for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the
>   status of the set. This has happened for 3 checks in a row.
>   2019-02-24T16:48:22.303-0800 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary
>   for set Cluster0-shard-0 2019-02-24T16:48:22.303-0800 I NETWORK  [js]
>   Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network
>   connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 4 checks
>   in a row. 2019-02-24T16:48:22.303-0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: connect
>   failed to replica set
>   Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-z4j9e.azure.mongodb.net.:27017
>   : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13 @(connect):1:6 exception:
>   connect failed

I can't seem to get it to work.  should I recreate the cluster? what else could I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Where u able to solve this issue?

Comment: no.  I destroyed/recreated the cluster

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same behavior trying to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster from Linux Mongo client.

The reason I was having this issue was related to version mismatch from client to the cluster. Mongo client was on v4.0.5 while the DB cluster was running on v4.0.6.

Updating Mongo client to version v4.0.6 has fixed the issue for me.

As for the issue with your node.js application, it could be unrelated to the mongo client issue you are seeing or it could be related to versioning just as well, so I would suggest seeing if the database connector you use has an update available.

EDIT: To expand a little on the error you got from your node application, there is [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153538/what-is-a-transienttransactionerror-in-mongoose-or-mongodb) talking about the exact error code you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a free and shared tier cluster, you can get these kind of mysterious transient errors when you run up against the [Operation Limits](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limitations) of these clusters. There doesn't seem yet to be a simple way to know if you have hit these in the web UI, but take a look at your metrics, and you can probably deduce if you have hit those.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your IP has changed so you need to whitelist your new one: Security > Network Access > Add IP address

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to connect to an old cluster for at least 2 hours because of that!